# Qt App bundle signing error: "A timestamp was expected but was not found" for QtCore and others

Tags: qt, mac-app-store, code-signing-certificate, apple-developer

I'm creating my Qt app bundle on macOS using command

`macdeployqt MyApp.app --verbose --executable=MyApp.app/Content/MacOS/MyApp -codesign=<identity>`

and getting such errors for all Qt libraries:

```
ERROR: Codesign signing error:
ERROR: "/Users/xxx/Projects/MyApp/deploy/MyAppapp/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore: A timestamp was expected but was not found.\n"
```

I can reproduce same errors if running `codesign` separately

```
codesign --sign "<identity>" /path/to/Fraworks/.../5/QtCore
```

My certificate is a fresh generated from Apple Developer website.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?